# Converting an RGB 300 dpi image to CMYK it changes DPI to 72. How can i keep the same DPI?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, cmyk, rgb, dpi

thank you for your replies.
I am new here and i didnt explain correctly.
So let me explain better the situation.

**TASK** (What i want to do)

The initial file is .png and has these settings: 333 dpi, width=14.015 inches and height=18.018 inches
I have to convert it to CMYK to work with it and then i have to export it as PNG keeping the initial settings of the file. (The reason i have to do this procedure is complicated and i will write it only if you need me to).

**WHAT I DO** to accomplish the above TASK:

1. I open the PNG file in photoshop 2020
2. I convert it with the "Convert to profile advance" to CMYK
3. I work on the file and then save it and because its CMYK i can't save it as PNG, so I save it as PSD
4. I export the file as PNG.
5. I open the exported PNG file to check the file and i see the settings changed to: 72 dpi, width=64.819 inches and height=83.333 inches which is not what i want to do.

So what am i doing wrong? What i have to do to accomplish the TASK?

Please advice.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Nik.

Comment: PPI should **never** change simply by changing the image mode. i.e. `Image > Mode > CMYK`. I mean **never**, honestly. If it is changing, you're doing something unusual. Please describe your *actual* exact steps.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  Changing the image mode from RGB to CMYK does not change the PPI of an image.

Comment: Possibly the process you did to get the image into photoshop changed it into 72 dpi not photoshop as such. Could you care to tell us what exactly you do. So start with what file format your image is how you open etc

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your answers. I am new here and i didnt explain correctly.
So i edited my initial post and explain better the situation.

Comment: Err theres no such thing as CMYK PNG so saving it as PNG defeats the purpose of even doing the conversion in first place. Use JPEG, TIF or PSD. Just do what Lucian says.

Comment: Step 4 is the problem.  PNGs are 72ppi, and don't support CMYK colour. You'll need to choose another format.  PNG is a web image format, and not really suitable for printing.

Answer (score 2):

So..

- You open the image
- You go to `Image > Mode > CMYK`
- And you get a CMYK converted image

The DPI will not change at this stage, however, what you do next is likely changing the DPI.

For instance, avoid using `Save for Web`, if you're doing that, this is likely the problem.

Try to use `Save As` and pick JPG, TIFF or PSD as the final format.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am new here and i didnt explain correctly. So i edited my initial post and explain better the situation.

Comment: @the_observer - Lucian's answer here will fix your problem.